# Netty channel that splits via a ChannelPool

Tags: kotlin, xmpp, netty

tldr; Can you have a netty channel that isn't connected to the network?

I am trying to implement a XMPP BOSH (Bidirectional streams Over Synchronous Http) client via netty. To do that, I need to manage multiple HTTP connections, so I naturally thought to use a ChannelPool. I still have state I need to manage though so I can't just have two different pipelines. I was thinking about using a Channel that when you get to the end uses the ChannelPool to get a connection and send the HTTP request. Then ChannelPool's pipeline coming in, transfer it to the main channel.

I would build the main pipeline via

```
        val initializer = object : ChannelInitializer<NettyChannel>() {
            override fun initChannel(ch: io.netty.channel.Channel) {
                ch.pipeline().apply { 
                    addLast(ConnectionManager(eventLoopGroup, remote, logger))
                    addLast(BoshHttpCodec(remote))
                    addLast(XmppProtocolBosh(
                        logger,
                        receivedChannel,
                        stanzaLogger,
                        xmlAsyncDeserializerFactory.create(),
                        xmlSerializer,
                        RequestIdGenerator(),
                    ))
                    addLast(ExceptionHandler(logger))
                }
            }
        }

        return Bootstrap()
            .group(eventLoopGroup)
            .channel(LocalChannel::class.java)
            .handler(initializer)
            .connect(LocalAddress("noop"))
            .noteFailure { "Failed to connect to '$remote'" }
```

and in ConnectionManager I would create my channel pool

```
    private var pool: SimpleChannelPool? = null

    override fun channelActive(ctx: ChannelHandlerContext) {
        super.channelActive(ctx)
        val context = ctx

        val bootstrap = Bootstrap()
            .group(eventLoopGroup)
            .channel(NoopChannel::class.java)
            .attr(AttributeKey.valueOf("Protocol"), TransportProtocol.TCP)
            .remoteAddress(remote.host, remote.portDefaulted())

        val handler = object : AbstractChannelPoolHandler() {
            override fun channelCreated(ch: Channel) {
                ch.pipeline().apply {
                    if (remote.scheme == "https") {
                        addLast(ch.ssl())
                    }
                    addLast(HttpClientCodec())
                    addLast(HttpObjectAggregator(8192))
                    addLast(PlainTextLoggingHandler(logger, NamedLogger::trace))
                    addLast(
                        object : ChannelInboundSink<Element>() {
                            override fun channelRead0(ctx: ChannelHandlerContext, msg: Element) {
                                context.pipeline().fireChannelRead(msg)
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        pool = FixedChannelPool(bootstrap, handler, 2)
    }
```

and it would forwards reads in that last ChannelHandler. It would forwards writes via

```
    override fun write(ctx: ChannelHandlerContext?, msg: Any?, promise: ChannelPromise?) {
        val pool = pool ?: return
        pool.acquire()
            .addListener { channelFuture ->
                if (channelFuture.isSuccess) {
                    val channel = channelFuture.now as Channel
                    channel.writeAndFlush(msg)
                    pool.release(channel)
                }
            }
    }
```

I tried using LocalAddress, but I think that requires a running LocalServerChannel. I even tried making my own NoopChannel, but that didn't change anything. I have been hammering away at this to no avail. Does netty just not support this?

Is there any way to have a channel that isn't connect to the network?

If you read all of this, Thank you for trying to help.